# VB.NET ASPX Dynamically Update Each TR in Table to Add Attribute to Each TR

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

Is it possible to run a VB.NET loop function to dynamically Update Each TR in a Table (using Class ID) to Add a dynamically generated Attribute into each TR?

e.g. AutoGen'd

```
<table class="DynaGenerated Content">
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

e.g. After running Function

```
<table class="DynaGeneratedContent">
<tr onclick='http://www.blah.com?id=1'><td></td></tr>
<tr onclick='http://www.blah.com?id=2'><td></td></tr>
<tr onclick='http://www.blah.com?id=3'><td></td></tr>
<tr onclick='http://www.blah.com?id=4'><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Appreciate any help i can get!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must add the `runat="server"` attribute and an `ID` to your table:

```
<table class="DynaGenerated Content" id="myTable" runat="server">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Then in the code-behind you can retrieve your table and apply the transformation:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Applytransform()
End Sub

Private Sub Applytransform()
    Dim counter As Integer = 1

    For Each row As HtmlTableRow In Me.myTable.Rows
        row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "http://www.blah.com?id=" & counter.ToString)
        counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

resulting markup after the transformation:

```
<table id="MainContent_myTable" class="DynaGenerated Content">
    <tr onclick="http://www.blah.com?id=1">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="http://www.blah.com?id=2">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="http://www.blah.com?id=3">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="http://www.blah.com?id=4">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```